# Echo php session variable on one page, set it on another with AJAX/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, variables

Say I have a simple html button on `main.php` that looks like this:

```
<button type="button" name="button" id="button">Search</button>
<div id="results">
<?php
session_start();
echo @$_SESSION['numbers'];
?>
</div>
```

This button calls an ajax query to `session.php` that looks like this:

```
session_start();
$_GET['numbers'] = $_SESSION['numbers'];
```

Is there a way to refresh or relead the div on `main.php` with JQuery/AJAX so that it will echo the now set $_SESSION['numbers']?

Answer (score 1):

the function jquery.ajax has an argument that works as an callback that is called when your ajax returns. (see [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) )
edit your session.php in that way that it returns the value from the session.
and write something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'session.php',
    data: {numbers:1337},
    success: myEventhandler
});

function() myEventhandler( value ) {
    $('#result').text( value );
}
```

the returning callback than outputs the value that comes from session.php.

btw, wouldn't that make more sense?

```
$_SESSION['numbers'] = $_GET['numbers'];
```

you're doing an assignment to the get array and are using it not later on.

Comment: Yes, this is only part of the issue resolved though. Doing what you suggested actually replaces all of div#result with the response text of the ajax query. I don't want to alter the div, only "reload" or "refresh" it.

Comment: well your question implies that nothing more than the number that's saved in the session is shown in the result. so i provided a solution that replaces the present value by the actual value. what else is in the result div?

Answer (score 1):

You have to echo what you want in `session.php`, such as

```
echo $_GET['number'];
```

and than when calling ajax in `main.php`, you can use the response data to modify current page, such as

```
$.get('session.php', function(response) {
    $('#result').text(response);
});
```

if not familiar with jQuery's ajax method, the [ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) might be helpful.